# How to use FXML document in a JFXtras window?

Tags: javafx, window, fxml, scenebuilder, jfxtras

For content of JFXtras window object, should we use only code part on IDE?

```
Window w = new Window("My Window#"+counter);
w.getContentPane().getChildren().add(new Label("Content... \nof the window#"));
root.getChildren().add(w);
```

For example, i prepared an fxml document with scene builder, i want it to be shown in jfxtras window. But i couldn't make the window  like a stage.

Answer (score 1):

Load fxml in `Node` and set as content

```
Node node = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("yourFxml.fxml"));
w.getContentPane().getChildren().add(node);
```

Comment: It is ok now.  my fxml file is in window but i think it is wrong. What is the problem sir?
http://s17.postimg.org/sa0ipwc9b/image1.png
http://s17.postimg.org/5ml9jqwpb/image2.png